# Scala and State Monad

Tags: scala, state-monad

I have been trying to understand the State Monad.  Not so much how it is used, though that is not always easy to find, either.  But every discussion I find of the State Monad has basically the same information and there is always something I don't understand.

Take [this](http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/memoisation-with-state-using-scala/index.html) post, for example.  In it the author has the following:

```
case class State[S, A](run: S => (A, S)) {
...
  def flatMap[B](f: A => State[S, B]): State[S, B] =
    State(s => {
      val (a, t) = run(s)
      f(a) run t
    })
...
}
```

I can see that the types line up correctly.  However, I don't understand the second `run` at all.

Perhaps I am looking at the whole purpose of this monad incorrectly.  I got the impression from the HaskellWiki that the State monad was kind of like a state-machine with the `run` allowing for transitions (though, in this case, the state-machine doesn't really have fixed state transitions like most state machines).  If that is the case then in the above code `(a, t)` would represent a single transition.  The application of `f` would represent a modification of that value and `State` (generating a new State object).  That leaves me completely confused as to what the second `run` is all about.  It would appear to be a second 'transition'.  But that doesn't make any sense to me.

I can see that calling `run` on the resulting `State` object produces a new `(A, S)` pair which, of course, is required for the types to line up.  But I don't really see what this is supposed to be doing.

So, what is really going on here?  What is the concept being modeled here?

**Edit: 12/22/2015**

So, it appears I am not expressing my issue very well.  Let me try this.

In the same blog post we see the following code for `map`:

```
def map[B](f: A => B): State[S, B] =
  State(s => {
    val (a, t) = run(s)
    (f(a), t)
  })
```

Obviously there is only a single call to `run` here.

The model I have been trying to reconcile is that a call to `run` moves the state we are keeping forward by a single state-change.  This seems to be the case in `map`.  However, in `flatMap` we have two calls to `run`.  If my model was correct that would result in 'skipping over' a state change.

To make use of the example @Filppo provided below, the first call to `run` would result in returning `(1, List(2,3,4,5))` and the second would result in `(2, List(3,4,5))`, effectively skipping over the first one.  Since, in his example, this was followed immediately by a call to `map`, this would have resulted in `(Map(a->2, b->3), List(4,5))`.

Apparently that is not what is happening.  So my whole model is incorrect.  What is the correct way to reason about this?

**2nd Edit: 12/22/2015**

I just tried doing what I said in the REPL.  And my instincts were correct which leaves me even more confused.

```
scala> val v = State(head[Int]).flatMap { a => State(head[Int]) }
v: State[List[Int],Int] = State(<function1>

scala> v.run(List(1,2,3,4,5))
res2: (Int, List[Int]) = (2,List(3, 4, 5))
```

So, this implementation of `flatMap` **does** skip over a state.  Yet when I run @Filippo's example I get the same answer he does.  What is really happening here?

Comment: BTW Michael Pilquist made a great presentation about `State Monad`, there is also a video online: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jg3Uv_YWJqI

Comment: I just watched part of that video.  Unfortunately, he did the same kind of 'hand-waving' about the second run as I have seen elsewhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To understand the "second run" let's analyse it "backwards".

The signature `def flatMap[B](f: A => State[S, B]): State[S, B]` suggests that we need to run a function `f` and return its result.

To execute function `f` we need to give it an `A`. Where do we get one?
Well, we have `run` that can give us `A` out of `S`, so we need an `S`.

Because of that we do: `s => val (a, t) = run(s) ...`. 
We read it as "given an `S` execute the `run` function which produces us `A` and a new `S`. And this is our "first" run.

Now we have an `A` and we can execute `f`. That's what we wanted and `f(a)` gives us a new `State[S, B]`. 
If we do that then we have a function which takes `S` and returns `Stats[S, B]`:

```
(s: S) => 
   val (a, t) = run(s)
   f(a) //State[S, B]
```

But function `S => State[S, B]` isn't what we want to return! We want to return just `State[S, B]`.

How do we do that? We can wrap this function into `State`:

```
State(s => ... f(a))
```

But it doesn't work because `State` takes `S => (B, S)`, not `S => State[B, S]`. 
So we need to get `(B, S)` out of `State[B, S]`.
We do it by just calling its `run` method and providing it with the state we just produced on the previous step! 
And it is our "second" run.

So as a result we have the following transformation performed by a `flatMap`:

```
s =>                   // when a state is provided
  val (a, t) = run(s)  // produce an `A` and a new state value
  val resState = f(a)  // produce a new `State[S, B]`
  resState.run(t)      // return `(S, B)`
```

This gives us `S => (S, B)` and we just wrap it with the `State` constructor.

Another way of looking at these "two runs" is:
*first*  - we transform the state ourselves with "our" `run` function
*second* - we pass that transformed state to the function `f` and let it do its own transformation.

So we kind of "chaining" state transformations one after another. And that's exactly what monads do: they provide us with the ability to schedule computation sequentially.

Comment: Thanks.  I went through a similar reasoning and came to the same conclusion.  But that still doesn't explain what the second `run` *does* (other than make the types work out right).  To spring off of your last comment why do we chain two transformations into a single mapping operation?  How can we justify that?

Comment: What it does? It runs the "second" state using the "intermediate" state provided. When the computation is executed, you want the state value to be transformed by "your" state monad and by the second one that is constructed by the function. This is exactly what happens. You return a computation that runs "this" state transformation and then "provided" state transformation. It needs to be run in the end of the day. The State that is returned from the `flatMap` just executes these two one-by-one.

Comment: take a look at my edit.  Hopefully that will better explain what I am missing.

Comment: I don't see why you say it skips anything. First you create a state with the `head` which, when evaluated, would give you `(1, List(2,3,4,5))`. Then you flatmap it. You chose to ignore the value `1` and further transform the state with the `head` function again. Which gives you `(2, List(3,4,5))`  
I don't see what is skept and where.

Comment: You are probably confused in understanding that `State(..)` doesn't do anything. It is just a function (it actually just wraps a function). 
All `flatMap` does is creates a function that will run the current state (1st `run`), then the stateful function you pass as an argument (the 2nd `run`) and returns will result. But it is still a function. You need to give it an initial `S` to trigger the computation.

Comment: The problem is more conceptual.  `flatMap` is often described as `map` followed by `flatten` (whatever that means in a given context).  However, as it is implemented in the State monad it appears to be `map` followed by `map` followed by a kind of `flatten`.  When you say it 'runs the current state' that implies (to me) that it increments to the 'next' state.  The next `run` then increments to the one following that - skipping the intermediate state.

Comment: A `map` operation would run the state once, get the result and wrap it into `State`. A `flatMap` is given with a function that results in yet another `State`. If you just `map` this function then you will have your `State[State[S, B]]` that you will have to flatten. How would you do it? Well, you would have to execute the "inner" state to take the value from it, wouldn't you? That's your second `run` and that's your `flatten`.

Answer (score 4):

The `state monad` boils down to this function from one `state` to another `state` (plus `A`):

```
type StatefulComputation[S, +A] = S => (A, S)
```

The implementation mentioned by Tony in that blog post "capture" that function into `run` of the `case class`:

```
case class State[S, A](run: S => (A, S))
```

The `flatmap` implementation to `bind` a `state` to another `state` is calling 2 different `run`s:

```
    // the `run` on the actual `state`
    val (a: A, nextState: S) = run(s)

    // the `run` on the bound `state`
    f(a).run(nextState)
```

---

**EDIT** Example of `flatmap` between 2 `State`

Considering a function that simply call `.head` to a `List` to get `A`, and `.tail` for the next state `S`

```
// stateful computation: `S => (A, S)` where `S` is `List[A]`
def head[A](xs: List[A]): (A, List[A]) = (xs.head, xs.tail)
```

A simple binding of 2 `State(head[Int])`:

```
// flatmap example
val result = for {
  a <- State(head[Int])
  b <- State(head[Int])
} yield Map('a' -> a,
            'b' -> b)
```

The expect behaviour of the `for-comprehension` is to "extract" the first element of a list into `a` and the second one in `b`. The resulting state `S` would be the remaining tail of the run list:

```
scala> result.run(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
(Map(a -> 1, b -> 2),List(3, 4, 5))
```

How? Calling the "stateful computation" `head[Int]` that is in `run` on some state `s`:

```
s => run(s)
```

That gives the `head` (`A`) and the `tail` (`B`) of the list. Now we need to pass the `tail` to the next `State(head[Int])`

```
f(a).run(t)
```

Where `f` is in the `flatmap` signature:

```
def flatMap[B](f: A => State[S, B]): State[S, B]
```

Maybe to better understand what is `f` in this example, we should de-sugar the `for-comprehension` to:

```
val result = State(head[Int]).flatMap {
  a => State(head[Int]).map {
    b => Map('a' -> a, 'b' -> b)
  }
}
```

With `f(a)` we pass `a` into the function and with `run(t)` we pass the modified state.

Comment: I still don't understand when you say the second run is on the 'bound' state.  What does that mean?

Comment: I mean is the `run` called on the second `State(head[Int])`

Comment: But that is the exact issue I am trying to get clear.  Why do we need the second `run` at all?  What problem does it solve?  What is the concept behind it?

Comment: Because the `state monad` is just that function `S => (A, S)`, within `flatmap` we need to pass the result state after our run to the next state. BTW the second `run` is not running anything until a `.run` from "outside" get invoked. The flatmap implementation is just binding them.

Comment: I realize it is a deferred operation.  But when it is finally applied we seem to get two 'transformations' for a single operation.  I just don't understand how we can justify this.

Comment: It is exactly what you described: two transformations in a single operation. That is what any `flatMap` would do. You must return the result of the second transformation, and to perform it you need a result of the first one. So you execute the first, then you execute the second, then you return the result.
That's what monads do: they represent computations in sequence.

Answer (score 4):

I have accepted @AlexyRaga's answer to my question.  I think @Filippo's answer was very good as well and, in fact, gave me some additional food for thought.  Thanks to both of you.

I think the conceptual difficulty I was having was really mostly to do with 'what does the `run` method 'mean'.  That is, what is its purpose and result.  I was looking at it as a 'transition' function (from one state to the next).  And, after a fashion, that is what it does.  However, it doesn't transition from a given (`this`) state to the next state.  Instead, it takes an initial `State` and returns the (`this`) state's value and a new 'current' state (not the **next** state in the state-transition sequence).

That is why the `flatMap` method is implemented the way it is.  When you generate a new `State` then you need the current value/state pair from it based on the passed-in initial state which can then be wrapped in a new `State` object as a function.  You are not really transitioning to a new state.  Just re-wrapping the generated state in a new `State` object.

I was too steeped in traditional state machines to see what was going on here.

Thank, again, everyone.

Comment: `initial state which can then be wrapped in a new State object as a function` exactly!