# Passing State monad result form one step to another in a program + stop early

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, scala-cats, for-comprehension

I have these steps:

```
trait BlackjackSteps {
    def gamerTakesTwoCards(gamerName:String): State[Deck, Gamer]
    def dealerTakesTwoCards: State[Deck, Dealer]
    def isBlackjack(gamer: Gamer, dealer: Dealer): Option[Player]
    def gamerDrawsCards(gamer: Gamer): State[Deck, Gamer]
    def dealerDrawsCards(dealer: Dealer, gamer: Gamer): State[Deck, Dealer]
    def determineWinner(gamer: Gamer, dealer: Dealer): Player

    def program(gamerName:String): State[Deck, Player] = for {
      gamer <- gamerTakesTwoCards(gamerName)
      dealer <- dealerTakesTwoCards
      //winner = isBlackjack(gamer, dealer)
      gamerFinal <- gamerDrawsCards(gamer)
      dealerFinal <- dealerDrawsCards(dealer, gamerFinal)
      winnerFinal = determineWinner(gamerFinal, dealerFinal)
    } yield  winnerFinal
  }
```

Two questions:

- **How do i get the Deck resulting from gamerTakesTwoCards and pass it to dealerTakesTwoCards?**
- **isBlackjack may result in a winner in which case I need to stop and return winner. How can I change the above code to do that?**

The Game:

- a gamer and dealer play
- they both draw two cards
- if no 21 winner
- players keep drawing cards until 17
- highest player not over 21 points wins!

Complete code here: https://bitbucket.org/jameskingconsulting/blackjack-scala/src/master/

Edit:

I've de-sugared the for-comprehension just make clear what's happening:

```
def program(gamerName:String): State[Deck, Player] =
      gamerTakesTwoCards(gamerName).flatMap( gamer =>
        dealerTakesTwoCards.flatMap(dealer =>
          isBlackjack(gamer, dealer).fold(

            gamerDrawsCards(gamer).flatMap( gamerFinal =>
              dealerDrawsCards(dealer, gamerFinal).map( dealerFinal =>
                determineWinner(gamerFinal, dealerFinal)
              )
            )

          )(State.pure[Deck, Player])
        ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Nothing to do. That's the whole point.
2. You have to return a winner *in both cases*, regardless of whether `isBlackjack` returns a `None` or a `Some`. Either way, you have to return a `State[Deck, Player]`. For example, you could achieve it with `fold` on the `Option`, mapping the success-case through `pure`:

   ```
   def program(gamerName:String): State[Deck, Player] = for {
     gamer <- gamerTakesTwoCards(gamerName)
     dealer <- dealerTakesTwoCards
     winner <- isBlackjack(gamer, dealer).fold(for {
       gamerFinal <- gamerDrawsCards(gamer)
       dealerFinal <- dealerDrawsCards(dealer, gamerFinal)
       winnerFinal = determineWinner(gamerFinal, dealerFinal)
     } yield winnerFinal)(State.pure[Deck, Player])
   } yield winner
   ```

Comment: thanks, for (1) I actually had a bug in my code that made me think Deck wasn't being passed correctly but now it's working fine. The one thing that i can't seem to visualise is the transfer of Deck from one step another. Can you share a link that explains how this happens?

Comment: @jakstack [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34407212/2707792) is a nice toy example. A `State[S, A]` is essentially just `S => (A, S)`, i.e. it takes old state, returns an `A` with the new state. Given a `State[S, A]` and an `f: A => State[S, B]`, you do the following: you start with the first state `s0` and feed it to the `State[S, A]`, which returns `(a, s1)`, where `s1` is the first modified state. Now you apply `f` to `a` and feed it with the updated state `s1`. This will return a `b: B` and an again updated state `s2`. The `(b, s2)` is the result that is returned in the end.

Comment: thanks, is the f: A => State[S, B] one of the steps in BlackjackSteps like gamerTakesTwoCards?

Comment: @jakstack The signature says it already: `gamerTakeTwoCards(s)` is of type `State[Deck, Gamer]`, which, as described above, is essentially just a fancy name for `Deck => (Gamer, Deck)`.